# How to select xcode supported platform

Tags: xcode

How do I display supported platforms option to appear in my new xcode file under build settings? I specifically want to select the iPhone operation system.

Answer (score 0):

I can't believe you're asking this, but here you go:

[image]

Comment: That is not what I was asking. The iphone supported platform field does not display in my xcode version 4.6.